# Floating bottom section we can show or hide

Tags: menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

Google doesn't give me good answers so it is time to ask to the community how to do !

I am a beginer in web development, and it is just for me, to show all my job experiences.

I want to do a bottom section which contains some buttons. This section must be always present (visible) during scrolling, and at the end of page, be under the footer... This section must have a auto size for height and centered in the page.

This is an begining of the work I done : http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1250/
It begins at line 102 :

```
<div id="base_bottom" class="IL_BASE" style="position: fixed; z-index: 9999999; width: 100%; /* height: 150px; */ /* left: 50%; */ border-top-width: 1px;  /* border-top-style: solid; */ border-top-color: rgb(0, 51, 102); border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-right-style: solid; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); bottom: 0px;margin-top: 5px;">
```

If someone can give me some advices, it will be great ;)

Thanks by advance,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add empty div before your bottom block

```
<div style="height:150px"></div>
```